# Enhance Distinct Query For A Table With Millions Of Records

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database that currently holds about 6 million records... And I need to query for distinct users in that table, while also adding filters, but the query is really slow, is there a way to enhance it using mysql, or should I consider other options for big data.

My Table Is Called Interests.
It holds, the user_id, the section_id, the property_type_id and the location_id, all of these fields are foreign keys (indexes) that map to "one to many" relationships. And what I want to achieve is something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM interests 
WHERE section_id = 1 
  AND property_type_id = 4 AND location_id = 2;
```

**EDIT**

Keep in mind that some criteria can be optional for example I could only search for section and location or location and property type etc... Also in future the filters can further expand like we could search for min price and maximum price which could also be optional.

**EDIT 2**

This is the Create Statement

```
CREATE TABLE `user_interests` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`section_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`property_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`status` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`min_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`max_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`interest_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`locations` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`auto_saved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`keyword` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `IDX_C854880E64D218E` (`location_id`),
KEY `IDX_C854880E9C81C6EB` (`property_type_id`),
KEY `IDX_C854880EA76ED395` (`user_id`),
KEY `IDX_C854880ED823E37A` (`section_id`),
KEY `IDX_C854880EF066BCDE` (`auto_saved`),
KEY `user_interests_group_idx` (`user_id`,`status`,`created_at`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_C854880E64D218E` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES 
`locations` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_C854880E9C81C6EB` FOREIGN KEY (`property_type_id`) 
REFERENCES `property_types` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_C854880EA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES 
`users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_C854880ED823E37A` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES 
`sections` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6530632 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

[image: These are my indexes and their cardinalities]

This is the explain statement
[image: This is the explain statement]

Comment: You'll have to create different indexes for different where clauses. Unfortunately you might end up with indexes whose total size is larger than the table itself, plus you'll have very slow inserts.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of A) EXPLAIN (your query); , B) SHOW CREATE TABLE interests; and C) SHOW INDEX FROM interests; so we can see your index cardinality numbers.  This information will help determine the best order for creating the multi-column index.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: Please reconsider and post B) SHOW CREATE TABLE interests; which will be much different than your create table posted.

Comment: I edited it as you stated. Please recheck.

Comment: Thank you for your replacement posting of SCT.  See my answer with alternative multi column index structure.

Answer (score 1):

Add a multi-column index like:

```
ALTER TABLE interests ADD INDEX (section_id, property_type_id, user_id);
```

The first two columns will optimize the `WHERE` clause, and `user_id` should optimize `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  please check the edit so you can understand my situation better.... These filters are optional based on what the user decides which filters to use and they could expand further to include price range too which is also optional...

Comment: There's no way to make indexes that will work for any combination of columns being searched. You have to determine which are common and important to optimize.

Comment: And if I can't determine which are common, and they are completely random based on the user's input? Then there is no way to optimize it using mysql right?

Comment: Right. You can try to estimate which are most likely.

Comment: Or you can create multiple indexes to handle several likely cases. But no, there's basically no way to _optimize_ any possible random query.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this multi column index,

```
ALTER TABLE user_interests 
ADD INDEX interests_idx_loc_propt_sec_uid (location_id,property_type_id,section_id,user_id) 
;
```

and reorder the columns in your where list to select highest cardinality first, such as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM user_interests 
WHERE 
location_id = 2
AND 
property_type_id = 4 
AND 
section_id = 1 
;
```

What does your new EXPLAIN look like and how long does it take to complete?

Comment: @brokleyscoding The order of columns in the table should not need to be changed.  You have the volume of data that would allow timing of execution time required with my suggested WHERE column order and Barmar's suggested order.  Do us all a huge favor, please and post the 'second execution' time required for Barmar and Wilson's suggested WHERE ordering.  Explain for each query would be great for us to see what the optimizer does with this volume of data when high cardinality is first in the list (and is a covering index).  Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar You asked the question 2 Comments ago.  You could delete your comment of yesterday since I clarified where the ordering should be considered in the WHERE part of the query.

Comment: There's no need to reorder the columns in the `WHERE` list. The query planner looks for the best index that covers the columns being tested. Order in the index matters, order in the `WHERE` clause doesn't.

Comment: I am hoping we get to see the 2 EXPLAINS.